Realizar Menús en Java de manera eficaz
Me justaría saber si hay algún método eficiente para hacer menús de forma mas funcional en un main en java, a mi se me ocurre algo como el código de abajo, esta incompleto pero me gustaría saber si voy bien encaminado para continuar con esta forma,
muchas gracias.
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  mostrarMensaje( "Bienvenido a la Biblioteca" );
  OpcionMenu opcion;
  do {
     mostrarMenuPrincipal();
     opcion = ingresarOpcionDelMenu();
     manejarOpcionMenu( opcion );
  }
  while( opcion != OpcionMenu.SALIR );
}

private static void mostrarMenuPrincipal() {
  for( OpcionMenu opcion: OpcionMenu.values() ) {
     System.err.println( opcion.getId() + ". " + opcion.getDescripcion() );
  }
}

private static OpcionMenu ingresarOpcionDelMenu() {
  mostrarMensaje( "Ingrese una opción:" );
  int idOpcion = teclado.nextInt();
  return OpcionMenu.fromId( idOpcion );
}

private static void manejarOpcionMenu( OpcionMenu opcion ) {
  switch( opcion ) {
     case INICIAR_SESION:
        break;
     case REGISTRARSE:
        break;
     case VER_LIBROS:
        break;
     case MI_CUENTA:
        break;
     case AGREGAR_LIBRO:
        break;
     case HACERME_SOCIO:
        break;
     case SALIR:
        mostrarMensaje( "Saliendo del programa." );
        break;
     default:
        mostrarMensaje( "Opción no válida. Por favor, intente de nuevo." );
        break;
  }
}


Hola user355651, bienvenido, en mi humilde opinión... vas bien encaminado.
